# Javac doesn't work in ant build

Tags: java, ubuntu, ant, javac, build.xml

I try to run javac in ant build.xml on command line on ubuntu 11.02.
After then running "ant deploy-live", the command line prints like:

```
Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1150)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:912)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:442)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

My task about javac:

```
<javac deprecation="true"
               includeantruntime="false"
               debug="true"
               debuglevel="${debuglevel}"
               destdir="${project.build.outputpath}"
               verbose="true"
               encoding="UTF-8">
            <src path="${project.src.classes}" />
            <compilerarg value="-Xlint" />
            <classpath refid="core.classpath" />
</javac>
```

**Os:**
Ubuntu 11.10 (oneiric)

**Java version:**
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0-b147)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0-b17, mixed mode)

**Ant version:** Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on August 19 2011

I tried about encoding build.xml file, but couldn't work.

Please help

Comment: What task are you using for compilation? <javac>?

Comment: you should post a snippet from your `build.xml` file and also a bit more of output from your Ant execution. At a first sight it just seems you have compilation errors, does the code compile when you work with an IDE?

Answer (score 1):

first you need to figure error details

try to run and with -debug or -verbose flags

http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html
Options that affect the amount of logging output by Ant are: -quiet, which instructs Ant to print less information to the console; -verbose, which causes Ant to print additional information to the console; and -debug, which causes Ant to print considerably more additional information.

And submit details of error here for subsequent analyze...